# JAVA Employee Type with Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, types

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       person_type salespeople[] = new person_type [100];
       person_type person = new person_type();
       int counter = 0;

       person.gross=0;
       person.salary=0;

       System.out.println("How many workers are there?");
       Scanner number_of_workers = new Scanner(System.in);
       counter=number_of_workers.nextInt();

       for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
       {
           salespeople[i] = person;
           System.out.println(person.salary);
       }

       for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
       {
           System.out.print("Enter the salary of the salesperson ");
           System.out.print(i+1); 
           System.out.println(":");
           Scanner salary = new Scanner(System.in);
           salespeople[i].salary = salary.nextInt();  


           System.out.print("Enter the gross of the salesperson ");
           System.out.print(i+1); 
           System.out.println(":");
           Scanner gross = new Scanner(System.in);

           salespeople[i].gross = gross.nextInt(); 

           System.out.println("1---- " + salespeople[0].salary);
           System.out.println(i);
       }

        System.out.println("First worker's salary is: " + salespeople[0].salary);
        System.out.println("First worker's gross " + salespeople[0].gross);

        System.out.println("Second worker's salary is: " + salespeople[1].salary);
        System.out.println("Second worker's gross is: " + salespeople[1].gross);
    }

    private static class person_type
    {
        int salary;
        int gross;        
    }

}
```

I am trying to put every employee stored to the array, but all the employees' details are overwritten by the very last one entered by the user. Can you please help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You're inserting the *same* `person` in the loop, the overriding is just an illusion. Please change class name to begin with uppercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the elements in the array refer to the same `person_type` instance :

```
for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
{
    salespeople[i] = person;
    System.out.println(person.salary);
}
```

You must create a new `person_type` instance for each index of the array.

```
for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
{
    salespeople[i] = new person_type ();
}
```

BTW, I suggest you change your class name to either `Person` or `PersonType` to conform to Java naming conventions.